# Can not rename column with underscore?

Tags: r

I am using the data found here: https://www.kaggle.com/cdc/behavioral-risk-factor-surveillance-system. In my R studio, I have named the csv file, BRFSS2015. Below is the code I am trying to execute.  I am trying to select two columns.

```
BRFSS2015%>%
  select(_STATE,MENTHLTH)
```

R studio will not load _STATE because of the underscore. I have tried renaming the column, using

`rename(BRFSS2015,STATE= _STATE)`.

This did not work.  I have also tried this method: `CDC_data=gsub("_","",names(BRFSS2015))`.  It did not work either.  Can someone please show me what to do?  Here is the error message:

`Error: unexpected input in: "BRFSS2015%>% select(_"`

Comment: `_state`, backtick it, ` at the beginning of the term ` at the end,  as you would if it were a variable starting with a number `1_good_variable` that killed me.

Comment: Please see the linked post on how to deal with syntactically invalid names, which applies to both base R `data.frame`s as well as `tibble`s.